# Webpack error, Loading chunk failed

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, babeljs

Stack: Webpack 4.16.0, Node8, Vuejs2

I am seeing the below error, whilst serving my Vuejs application.

```
Error: Loading chunk 4 failed.
(missing: https://myapp.com/ui.chunk.bundle.js)
    at HTMLScriptElement.s (demo:1)
```

This error is consistent across builds, the actual file itself is accesible via the URL.

I am using code splitting via `import()` and the initial app loads fine, but then the flow will break when another chunk is loaded, it can also vary between `ui.chunk.bundle.js` & `vendors~ui.chunk.bundle.js`.

When building for production, a new error is shown, but it seems related as also linked to loading modules:

```
demo:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at o (demo:1)
    at Object.349 (ui.chunk.bundle.js:1)
    at o (demo:1)
    at o.t (demo:1)
```

I have tried upgrading webpack and babel, but am at a loss as to what this could be down to as it was working perfectly fine before.

When running the application on my local machine and not Google App Engine, everything seems fine.

**How the app is loaded:**
It is loaded into other website via a script tag, so `domainA.com` runs the script tag which calls `myapp.com/js` and the flow begins, i.e the app loads various chunks based on some logic.

When accessing the webpack generated index page bundle at myapp.com everything loads correctly.

Please help!

Comment: were you able to find something useful in fixing this error?

Comment: Upgrading webpack solved it as some point.

Comment: Do you have filenameHashing disabled? Then the browser might load an old (cached) version of the JS files. Had run into the same problem a while ago..

Comment: I think Webpack 4 made non-existent imports a warning instead of an error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071942/webpack-fails-silently-when-named-import-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 1):

That is rather deep and surely not easily fixed in two steps, best you create a new project using cli, if convenient with recommended presets, and if it still persist check the npm packages you installed and make sure none of them are discontinued and are up-to-date at least according to your version of vue.

Answer (score 1):

Its might be due to "webpack.config.js" where you can just try with updating output object

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.[chunkhash].js',
  }
};
```

Hope it should work!

Answer (score -1):

This might be a cross site scripting problem.
Make sure that myapp.com sets the correct headers.

On myapp.com, set this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://domainA.com
```

You should also make sure, that your script tag has async set to false:

```
<script async="false" …
```